# How to get every paired value as a separate list |python|

Tags: python, list, tuples

```py
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [4, 5, 6]

res = next(zip(a, b))
print(res)
```

Output:

```
(1,4)
```

how to get every pair in aa a separate list?

Expected Output:

```
[1,4]
[2,5]
[3,6]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can zip the items in a list and unpack them in a list comp.

```
new_list = [[x,y] for x,y in  zip(a,b)]
```

---

```
print(new_list)
[[1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6]]
```

the issue with your solution is your first turning your lists into an `iterator` (correct) but you are only calling the first value with `next`